# No internet after power outage

Tags: networking, server, internet

Hello yesterday I had a power outage on my server running Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS. After the power outage I realized I couldn't ping anything so I immediately checked the network adapter and it is appearing on ubuntu  using #lspci. I went into the bios and noticed that the network adapter was blinking with the ethernet cable in it but when I booted into ubuntu it stopped. I've already attempted to reset the bios, use a different port and Ethernet cable. Internet is working fine everywhere else. I've been pulling my hair out trying to solve this so any advice on how to fix it would be greatly appreciated thanks!

My network topology is a computer connected to a networking switched which is connected directly to the router. Switch and cable has already been checked as a point of failure.

Edit: When booting into Ubuntu Home on same hardware internet works fine.

**With onboard ethernet**

```
      *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 03
       serial: b4:2e:99:37:96:24
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k firmware=0. 6-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:38 memory:f7400000-f741ffff ioport:f000(size=32) memory:f7420000-f7423fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: veth8ccdf40
       serial: 96:3c:c7:77:5b:8c
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: vethe78e395
       serial: 8a:79:ec:c3:1f:3e
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: veth5d2f953
       serial: 96:42:dd:ae:ae:52
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:3
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: veth4f8fb2c
       serial: de:1d:a0:a5:de:a8
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:4
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 5
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:2e:f0:65:e4
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:5
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 6
       logical name: veth79ceca4
       serial: a2:b9:77:11:57:7c
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:6
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 7
       logical name: veth2ffa2a6
       serial: d2:b6:bd:e0:a6:c0
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:7
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 8
       logical name: veth902f706
       serial: 62:b7:aa:97:13:2c
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:8
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 9
       logical name: vethf5875fa
       serial: 9e:47:b1:e2:c6:c8
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
```

**With Ethernet adapter**

```
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 03
       serial: b4:2e:99:37:96:24
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k firmware=0. 6-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:38 memory:f7400000-f741ffff ioport:f000(size=32) memory:f7420000-f7423fff
  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: veth8ccdf40
       serial: 96:3c:c7:77:5b:8c
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:1 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enxa0cec819afb3
       serial: a0:ce:c8:19:af:b3
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.09.9 duplex=full link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
  *-network:2
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: vethe78e395
       serial: 8a:79:ec:c3:1f:3e
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:3
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 4
       logical name: veth5d2f953
       serial: 96:42:dd:ae:ae:52
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:4
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 5
       logical name: veth322071d
       serial: 66:3c:29:3d:31:6a
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:5
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 6
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:2e:f0:65:e4
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=yes multicast=yes
  *-network:6
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 7
       logical name: veth79ceca4
       serial: a2:b9:77:11:57:7c
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:7
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 8
       logical name: veth2ffa2a6
       serial: d2:b6:bd:e0:a6:c0
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:8
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 9
       logical name: veth902f706
       serial: 62:b7:aa:97:13:2c
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
  *-network:9
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: a
       logical name: vethf5875fa
       serial: 9e:47:b1:e2:c6:c8
       size: 10Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=veth driverversion=1.0 duplex=full link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=10Gbit/s
```

**Netplan**

```
    # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp6s0:
      dhcp4: yes
```

Comment: Welcome! Maybe a different pci slot?

Comment: @terrance Thanks! I didn't think to try that after doing that twice I'm still unable to ping anything local or external

Comment: @guillermochamorro Thanks! Sorry I didn't mean to say network adapter I meant networking card since its built into my motherboard and is used via Ethernet. I only have one port on the board to use also.

Comment: @terrance Thanks I looked for a PCI Ethernet card around my house but couldn't find one. I found a USB to Ethernet adapter and used that and had the same issue though. My initial thought was that since it was blinking on the bios it would be a issue with something on the OS. I'm still not sure if the port is the issue but i'll try booting into a different OS via usb to test that right now.

Comment: Ah, I missed the link during your BIOS part.  What is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`?

Comment: Don't start reconfiguring your hardware as per the other comments. Let's collect some data first. Describe how your server is cabled, all the way to the router/modem. Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` (with the USB ethernet adapter plugged in, and the onboard ethernet cabled up) and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss it.

Comment: @heynnema I've added add the info asked for and when I attempted to boot into Ubuntu Home on the same hardware internet worked fine so I strongly believe its a software issue over hardware.

Comment: @Terrance I've just added it to the post

Comment: Let me take a look...

Comment: Please see my answer. Try the onboard ethernet first. Only have one ethernet interface cabled at a time. Report back.

Comment: What do you mean "booting into Ubuntu home"? Do you mean a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: You didn't show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together a /etc/netplan/*.yaml file that will drive either your onboard ethernet, or the USB ethernet adapter. Only connect one at a time. Try the onboard ethernet first. Try the USB ethernet adapter if you care to. Either should be working now.

Change your /etc/netplan/*.yaml file to this... keep the indentation, spacing, and no tabs, exactly as you see it...

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp7s0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
    enxa0cec819afb3:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
```

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply new config

`reboot` # this is optional right now, but we'll want to do it later

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've just edited it exact to what you had and generated and started getting feedback from the Ethernet cable. I don't have any domain name resolution but that's probably a separate issue. Thanks for all the help everyone!